# Javascript toggle only click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oop, toggle

I have the following object:

```
Toggle = {
    hidden: '.hidden-assisting',
    trigger: '.multiple',
    init: function() {
        $(this.trigger).click(this.toggleList.bind(this));
    },
    toggleList: function(event) {
        // toggle hidden elements
        $(event.currentTarget).siblings().slideToggle();
    }
};
```

My html looks like this:

```
<ul class="needs-padding">
  <a class="multiple" href="#">Multiple</a>
  <li class="hidden-assisting" style="display: none;">Eva-Marie Fox</li>
  <li class="hidden-assisting" style="display: none;">Linda Seigler</li>
  <li class="hidden-assisting" style="display: none;">Frank Giampietro</li>
  <li class="hidden-assisting" style="display: none;">Ken Gallagher</li>
  <li class="hidden-assisting" style="display: none;">Patrick Walsh</li>
</ul>
```

However these `.multiple` links and `.hidden-assisting` list items exist all over the page, so clicking one `.multiple` anchor opens all list items on the page.  How can I use this object to only toggle the direct sibling list items?

Comment: _"My html looks like this:"_ , _"However these '.multiple' links and '.hidden-assisting' list items exist all over the page"_ Can you include full `html` ?

Comment: Thanks, edited above.

Comment: _"clicking one .multiple anchor opens all list items on the page."_ Cannot reproduce. Is requirement to toggle single `.hidden-assisting` element on `click` ? Or all `.hidden-assisting` elements ?

Comment: No, requirement is to toggle all inside of that specific ul. But there are many other ul's on the page with .multiple anchors and 'hidden-assisting' li's.  All of those other instances are triggered

Comment: _"But there are many other ul's on the page with .multiple anchors and 'hidden-assisting' li's. All of those other instances are triggered"_ Can you reproduce this effect at stacksnippets or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net ? Tried js at Question at stacksnippets which appeared to return expected results. How are you calling `Toggle.init()`

Comment: inside of a $(document).ready(function());

Comment: Can you reproduce _"All of those other instances are triggered"_ at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net ? Could not reproduce that effect , here , given `html` and `js` at original Question

Comment: Not exactly related, but you should not place an anchor tag directly inside a ul/ol tag. Place it inside a li instead